# Python value unpacking error

Tags: python, django

I'm building a per-user file browsing/uploading application using Django and when I run this function

```
def walkdeep(request, path):
    path, dirs, files = walktoo('/home/damon/walktemp/%s' % path)
    return render_to_response('walk.html', {
        'path' : path[0],
        'dirs' : path[1],
        'files' : path[2],
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def walktoo(dir):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        yield path, dirs, files
    print path, dirs, files
```

I get this error:

`need more than 1 value to unpack`

Also, i know this is a silly way to do this, any advice would be appreciated.

edit:

this was actually very silly on my part, i completely forgot about os.listdir(dir) which is a much more reasonable function for my purposes. if you use the selected answer, it clears up the above issue i was having, but not with the results i wanted.

Comment: Which line does the error come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
path, dirs, files = walktoo('/home/damon/walktemp/%s' % path)
```

In this line, you're expecting `walktoo` to return a tuple of three values, which are then to be unpacked into `path`, `dirs`, and `files`.  However, your `walktoo` function is a generator object: calling `walktoo()` yields a single value, the generator.  You have to call `next()` on the generator (or call it implicitly by doing some sort of iteration on it) to get what you actually want, namely the 3-tuple that it yields.

I'm not entirely clear what you want to do -- your `walkdeep()` function is written like it only wants to use the first value returned by `walktoo()`.  Did you mean to do something like this?

```
for path, dirs, files in walktoo(...):
    # do something
```

Comment: What I want do do is create 1 level of a file tree (the root directory, the folders inside, and the files) and pass those values to the template at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield), this is another approach to get one layer of os.walk(dir).

```
path, dirs, files = [_ for _ in os.walk('/home/damon/walktemp/%s' % path)][0]
```

This is as an alternative to your walktoo(dir) funciton.

Also, make sure your second parameter to `render_to_response` uses the variables you created:

```
{'path' : path,
 'dirs' : dirs,
 'files' : files,}
```

`path` is a string, so by saying `path[0]` ... `path[1]` ... `path[2]` you're actually saying to use the first, second, and third character of the string.